# How to save Video file in DB?

Tags: asp.net, html, video

I have a task to insert Video in DB and display it by Html5 video control. I did my code well and the video saved well in DB but when I tried to play the video it doesn't and when I checked my code I found that the video saved in DB with this path `~/res/Files/`. When I
 removed the `~/` as the path will be `res/Files/` it worked well. How can I solve this issue?

```
protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, ImageClickEventArgs e)
{
    btier.AddObject("~/res/Files/" + FUFile.FileName);
    FUFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath("~/res/Files/" + FUFile.FileName));
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason being, you are passing the path as a string parameter to your method `AddObject` and to `MapPath`. Hence the path will remain "~/res/..." instead of resolving to the application root.

You have to first resolve the root and then save that path. One safe option is to use `VirtualPathUtility`. Something like this:

```
tempVar = VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/res/Files/" + FUFile.FileName);
btier.AddObject(tempVar);
FUFile.SaveAs(Server.MapPath(tempVar));
```

Where `tempVar` is a string variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void btnUpload_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (BinaryReader br = new BinaryReader(FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream))
    {
        byte[] bytes = br.ReadBytes((int)FileUpload1.PostedFile.InputStream.Length);
        string strConnString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(strConnString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                cmd.CommandText = "insert into tblFiles(Name, ContentType, Data) values (@Name, @ContentType, @Data)";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", Path.GetFileName(FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName));
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@ContentType", "video/mp4");
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Data", bytes);
                cmd.Connection = con;
                con.Open();
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                con.Close();
            }
        }
    }
    Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
}
```

Complete step by step tutorial:

http://www.aspsnippets.com/Articles/Upload-Save-Retrieve-and-Play-MP4-Video-files-with-live-streaming-from-Database-in-ASPNet-using-C-and-VBNet.aspx